# SQL Select for unique value in a column

Tags: sql, select, plsql

I have a table like

```
| ID | COL1 | COL2 |
| 1  |   1  |  w   |
| 1  |   2  |  x   |
| 2  |   1  |  y   |
| 2  |   2  |  z   |
```

When I query it, I'd like to get

```
| ID | COL2:1 | COL2:2 |    <--- (when COL1=1 and COL1 =2)
| 1  |   w    |    x   |
| 2  |   y    |    z   |
```

I've tried  `GROUP BY` and `JOIN` for the same table but I get duplicates and not grouped data.  I need some pointers for how to get the results I'm expecting.

Comment: Include the query that you've tried in your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `MAX()` and a `CASE` statement for this:

```
SELECT ID
      ,MAX(CASE WHEN Col1 = 1 THEN Col2 END) AS Col2_1
      ,MAX(CASE WHEN Col1 = 2 THEN Col2 END) AS Col2_2
FROM YourTable
GROUP BY ID
```

Demo: [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/63c03/2/0)

Comment: +1 for SQL Fiddle... I didn't know about that site :)

Comment: Thank you Goat CO !! i owe you a big one!
it seems i need to use the MAX function just to be able to GROUP BY, thank you, Great the [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/63c03/2/0) i will use it!